# entity framework over wcf

Tags: wcf, entity-framework

its there a way to expose a full ef model over wcf without custom coding every individual method individually? I know I can expose odata end point, but that interface is rather limited.

I want to abstract my data context away from my repositories so that they won't care if they are talking to objectcontext or some wcf endpoint.

I have firewall in between my database and some of my clients who I trust to connect securely

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't like OData endpoint (WCF Data Services) and you expect that your program will work both with local context (direct EF access) and remote context (WCF) you are going to code it whole yourselves and it will be a lot of work.

Comment: got it, thank you... has anyone created any abstractions over ObjectContext and DataContext that can make the task of mixing the two contexts easier?